# Elastic Search query_string query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic search query_string string in the following way:

```
{
    "query_string": {
                    "query": "*@test*",
                    "fields": ["title^6", "fulltext", "fields.value"],
                    "default_operator": "OR"
                }
}
```

The above query not giving any result. But when I updated the query like the following format it is giving me a valid result:

```
{
    "query_string": {
                    "query": "@test",
                    "fields": ["title^6", "fulltext", "fields.value"],
                    "default_operator": "OR"
                }
}
```

Can you please let me know what is wrong in first query I am using *@test* in first query.
Please help me in this?

Comment: What happens if you add `"analyze_wildcard": true` in your first query?

Comment: which elastic version are you using ?

Comment: I have added analyze_wildcard: true in the above query but getting the same result. Please let me know what is wrong here?